# CSS Menu Problem with IE8 - Debugging

Tags: css, internet-explorer, menu

It's a simple css menu on [this page.](http://yogadetoxretreat.co.uk/yoga-pilates.html) It works fine in Chrome. This is the relevant CSS that I'm using.

```
ul#list-nav {
    clear:both;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0 0px;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
}
ul#list-nav {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
}
ul#list-nav li {
    display:inline
}
ul#list-nav li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:5px 0;
    width:16.62%;
    background:#754C78;
    color:#eee;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    border-left:1px solid #fff;
}
```

It's mainly a problem with the `width`, but also something strange happening with the last two cells in the right since they're dipping slightly?

I appreciate any suggestions.

Thank you,

Tara

Comment: first try simplifying the whole thing, as there are more inconsistencies; like not enough width for floating in Fx; the bumping of the two last buttons appears also in Opera; for example, why do you have an `float:left;` on the anchors, while the parent `LI`s already have an `display:inline;`, which causes a similar effect…

Comment: The website is appearing fine for me in all browsers, though looking at your code I can see you have not closed off `display:inline` with a semicolon.

Comment: @Tara whether or not it seems ok in all browsers. The problem lies in basic things in the code. if you set the Width of each `menu li`  to one that matches the white lines in the images at the top, the overall width of the menu will be too big. Not by much but still. I would probably set the height of them so that it only fills the area of 800px width and then set the sidebar and top images width so that it matches the menu. I recall that you use chrome. In chrome if you right click anywhere, you should see `Inspect element` in the list use the developer tool to inspect elements It helps a lot

Comment: @lollero Yes, the problem is that it's showing up slightly different in different browsers... I don't understand, did you mean to write height or width?

Comment: @Tara i made you example of how i might do this menu. http://jsfiddle.net/WVx4N/

Comment: I forgot that there was white lines between every menu item so uuhm.. Heres and update: http://jsfiddle.net/WVx4N/2/

Comment: @lollero Thank you, but for some reason it's coming out broken for me (in the jsfiddle side).

Comment: @Tara It's just that the images were not loading. http://jsfiddle.net/WVx4N/3/

Answer (score 0):

remove the width and adding 38px for `padding-left` and `padding-right`

```
ul#list-nav li a {
background:#754C78 none repeat scroll 0 0;
border-left:1px solid #FFFFFF;
color:#EEEEEE;
float:left;
padding:6px 38px;
text-align:center;
text-decoration:none;
}
```